# Can't call callback with nodejs, aws lambda and aws api gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am having trouble making the callback in lambda to send a response in API Gateway. I am trying to build a simple application that interacts with a MySQL database. Relevent code snippet is below.

The issue is that even though validateToken will return an error and I will see the console.log message the done/callback will never send the expected response to the api gateway and will continue to process any code after it.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
        statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
        body: err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(res),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });

    if (event.path.match(/myApi\/workers\/*/)) {
      // Validate Token
      token.validateToken(pool, event.headers, function(err, result) {
        if (result.status == 'error') {
          console.log('Made it to here')
          done({"message": "Invalid api-token"}, null);
        } else {
          // Proceed with fetching workers
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the function work in the Lambda test console? How long does the function take to process?

Comment: It works as in it doesn't throw an error but it also doesn't return the "Invalid api-token" as it is expected to. I have been doing most of my testing through the API Gateway tester in the console. Ran a test through the Lambda one as well for this.

Comment: Sorry forgot to answer your "how long does it take to process" question. It currently times out since it doesn't ever return.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out my problem was the same that was posted here.

[AWS Lambda function never calls the callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570839/aws-lambda-function-never-calls-the-callback)

I tried to simplify the code by removing the mysql part and didn't realize that was what was causing the issue.