# Sub callback in NodeJS for AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, api, amazon-web-services, lambda

How can my AWS Lambda make an API call to some external service and return the output to the user who invoked the function please?

My piece of code looks like this:

```
module.exports.oauth_callback = (event, context, callback) => {
  oauth2.authorizationCode.getToken({
    redirect_uri: 'https://' + event.headers.Host + event.requestContext.path
    }).then(results => {
      callback(null, {statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(results)});
  });
};
```

With this, I receive a `500 Internal Error` because I believe the lambda function is exiting before returning the result.

EDIT Case number 2:
Actually in the case where I add another callback like this:

```
  return oauth2.authorizationCode.getToken({
      code: code,
    }).then(results => {
      createFirebaseAccount(results).then(token => {
        const template = signInFirebaseTemplate(token);
        return callback(null, { statusCode: 200, body: template.toString() });
      });
  });
};
```

My variable `template` has its value but the next callback never returns and my function times out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to return your promise from `getToken()`, like this:

```
module.exports.oauth_callback = (event, context, callback) => {
  return oauth2.authorizationCode.getToken({
      redirect_uri: 'https://' + event.headers.Host + event.requestContext.path
    }).then(results => {
      callback(null, {statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(results)});
    });
};
```

If that doesn't work, check your CloudWatch log under the monitoring tab of your Lambda.

Comment: I edited my question, I am wondering what to do with that second callback please ? I get a timeout while it is supposed to be returned

Comment: edit: i might have found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791258/lambda-timing-out-after-calling-callback